# Pivot/Unpivot table in ABAP CDS

Tags: pivot-table, abap, cds

Is it possible to do pivot query in ABAP CDS query? Is there a way we can achieve this like what we are always doing in SQL server and MySQL?

Comment: Which ABAP and SAP version are we talking about? At least for ABAP 7.5x on SAP R/3 the answer is no. You probably need to define a CDS according to the pivoted table and overwrite / redefine all the data provisioning methods by which you're gonna lose most of the feature CDS provide out of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, currently it is not supported natively neither in ABAP CDS nor in HANA.

There are several workarounds you can use to simulate pivot behavior:

1. Pivoting with `COUNT` and `UNION ALL` [[sample]](https://blogs.sap.com/2017/07/10/pivot-data-in-hana/)

   ```
   select vendor_id, sum("E1") AS "E1", SUM("E2") AS "E2", SUM("E3") AS "E3"
   FROM
   (
   select vendor_id, COUNT(NUM) as "E1", 0 AS "E2" , 0 AS "E3"
   from "ABHISHEAGRAW".
   WHERE EMP_ID = 'E1' GROUP BY vendor_id
   union all
   select vendor_id, 0 AS “E1”, COUNT(NUM) as "E2", 0 AS "E3"
   from "ABHISHEAGRAW".
   WHERE EMP_ID = 'E2' GROUP BY vendor_id
   union all
   select vendor_id, 0 AS “E1”, 0 as "E2", COUNT(NUM) AS "E3"
   from "ABHISHEAGRAW".
   WHERE EMP_ID = 'E3' GROUP BY vendor_id
   ) GROUP BY vendor_id ORDER BY vendor_id
   ```
2. Pivoting with `COUNT` through `CASE` [[sample]](https://blogs.sap.com/2017/07/10/pivot-data-in-hana/)

   ```
   select vendor_id, sum("E1") AS "E1", SUM("E2") AS "E2", SUM("E3") AS "E3"
   FROM
   (
   select vendor_id, CASE (EMP_ID) WHEN 'E1'
   THEN 1
   ELSE 0
   END as "E1",
   CASE (EMP_ID) WHEN 'E2'
   THEN 1
   ELSE 0
   END as "E2",
   CASE (EMP_ID) WHEN 'E3'
   THEN 1
   ELSE 0
   END as "E3"
   from “ABHISHEAGRAW”.
   )GROUP BY vendor_id ORDER BY vendor_id
   ```
3. Pivoting with CASE and grouping [[sample]](https://blogs.sap.com/2019/04/21/how-to-pivotunpivot-in-sap-hana/)

The given snippets are HANA examples but they can be adapted to ABAP CDS. If you give a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your case, we can propose you a possible solution.