# Multiple SUM aggregates in ABAP CDS

Tags: abap, cds

I have a table of work orders with different status and multiple plants like below:

| Plant | OrderID | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Plant1 | Order1 | OPEN |
| Plant1 | Order2 | RELEASED |
| Plant1 | Order3 | COMPLETED |
| Plant1 | Order4 | OPEN |
| Plant1 | Order5 | RELEASED |
| Plant1 | Order6 | COMPLETED |
| Plant2 | Order7 | RELEASED |
| Plant2 | Order8 | COMPLETED |

And I want to create a CDS to get the totals per plant: "total orders" plus a column for each status aggregate. The expected result is the following:

| Plant | Total Orders | Open | Released | Completed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Plant1 | 6 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| Plant2 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 1 |

Since subqueries are not possible, the only solution I could think was a CDS for each aggregate. 1 for plant total and 1 for each plant status. And finally a top CDS with the expected result.

But this seems a lot of CDS for something that should be relatively simple, because in reality I have 7 different status and not only 3. Is there a better alternative to my solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [CASE...WHEN...THEN...ELSE-expressions](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-us/abencds_f1_case_expression.htm) in your field list to convert the `Status` to multiple columns which contain either the integer 0 or the integer 1 depending on the value of `Status`:

```
define view VIEWNAME as select from DATABASE_TABLE {
    key OrderId,
    Plant,
    CASE Status WHEN 'OPEN' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Open,
    CASE Status WHEN 'RELEASED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Released,
    CASE Status WHEN 'COMPLETED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Completed
}
```

Now you can create a *second* view which queries this *first* view. Make that view `GROUP BY Plant`. Then use `COUNT( * )` to get the total number of orders per plant and SUM on the Open, Released and Completed fields to get their respective counts:

```
define view VIEWNAME2 as select from VIEWNAME {
    key Plant,
    COUNT( * ) as TotalOrders,
    SUM( Open ) AS Open,
    SUM( Released ) AS Released,
    SUM( Completed ) AS Completed
}
GROUP BY Plant
```

Comment: Why are two views needed? Can't one [nest](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-us/abencds_f1_aggregate_functions.htm) `SUM( CASE Status WHEN 'Open' THEN 1 ELSE 0 )` ?

Comment: Thanks @Philipp. that works! I was getting overflow in the SUM, so I added a `cast( case Status when 'RELEASED' then 1 else 0 end as abap.int8 ) as Released`, in the first CDS and it got solved. I tried to use the SUM in a single CDS, I think it could work, but then it's not allowed to do the CAST inside a SUM to use a larger type so I get the overflow error

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve pivoting is to use UNION, following the same approach I [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58582982/911419) for HANA CDS.  It is another flavor of the way Philipp used.

First view to unionize the status sums:

```
define view ZORDERS (plant, TOTAL, OPENED, RELEASED, COMPLETED) as 
select from zplants {
    plant, count(distinct orderid ) as TOTAL, 0 as OPENED, 0 as RELEASED, 0 as COMPLETED
}  group by plant
union
select from zplants {
    plant, 0 as TOTAL, count(distinct orderid ) as OPENED, 0 as RELEASED, 0 as COMPLETED
} where status = 'OPENED' group by plant
union
select from zplants {
    plant, 0 as TOTAL, 0 as OPENED, count(distinct orderid ) as RELEASED, 0 as COMPLETED
} where status = 'RELEASED' group by plant
union
select from zplants {
    plant, 0 as TOTAL, 0 as OPENED, 0 as RELEASED, count(distinct orderid ) as COMPLETED
} where status = 'COMPLETED' group by plant
```

Second view to aggregate them:

```
define view ZPIVOT as select from ZORDERS {
    plant,
    sum ( TOTAL ) as TOTAL, 
    sum ( OPENED ) as OPENED, 
    sum ( RELEASED ) as RELEASED,
    sum ( COMPLETED ) as COMPLETED
} group by plant
```

NB: here I used `OPENED` because `OPEN` is a reserved word in ABAP CDS.