# Table pivoting via ABAP with dynamic number of columns?

Tags: dynamic, pivot, abap, alv, internal-tables

I have the following source sample data (which will be populated from a dictionary table but I am supplying the values manually for demo purpose):

[image]

What I am trying to get is the pivot-version of sums-per-week assuming I do not know how many weeks I will have in source and what their (6-digit numeric) values will be at the time of pivot creation:

[image]

Here is the code to reproduce the results from the sample data:

```
************************************** Declare Data types: ******************************************
TYPES:  BEGIN OF strct_week,
              wk_header(8) TYPE c, wk_number TYPE i, amt_per_wk TYPE i,
        END OF strct_week,

        BEGIN OF strct_week_pivot,
              sum_per_wk1 TYPE i, sum_per_wk2 TYPE i, sum_per_wk3 TYPE i,
        END OF strct_week_pivot,

        "table definition:
        tb_week TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF strct_week WITH DEFAULT KEY,
        tb_week_pivot TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF strct_week_pivot WITH DEFAULT KEY.

DATA:   ls_week         TYPE strct_week,
        ls_week_pivot   TYPE strct_week_pivot,
        gt_weeks        TYPE tb_week,
        gt_weeks_pivot  TYPE tb_week_pivot,
        fc_tmp_data     TYPE lvc_s_fcat,
        fc_acc_data     TYPE lvc_t_fcat,
        fc_tmp_pivot    TYPE lvc_s_fcat,
        fc_acc_pivot    TYPE lvc_t_fcat.

************************************** Fill gt_weeks with sample data: ********************************
ls_week-wk_header = '202201'.
ls_week-wk_number = 01.
ls_week-amt_per_wk = 11111.
APPEND ls_week TO gt_weeks.

ls_week-wk_header = '202201'.
ls_week-wk_number = 01.
ls_week-amt_per_wk = 111111.
APPEND ls_week TO gt_weeks.

ls_week-wk_header = '202202'.
ls_week-wk_number = 02.
ls_week-amt_per_wk = 22222.
APPEND ls_week TO gt_weeks.

ls_week-wk_header = '202202'.
ls_week-wk_number = 02.
ls_week-amt_per_wk = 222222.
APPEND ls_week TO gt_weeks.

ls_week-wk_header = '202203'.
ls_week-wk_number = 03.
ls_week-amt_per_wk = 33333.
APPEND ls_week TO gt_weeks.

ls_week-wk_header = '202203'.
ls_week-wk_number = 03.
ls_week-amt_per_wk = 333333.
APPEND ls_week TO gt_weeks.

************************************** Fill gt_weeks_pivot with pivot of sample data: **********************
ls_week_pivot-sum_per_wk1 = 11111 + 111111.
ls_week_pivot-sum_per_wk2 = 22222 + 222222.
ls_week_pivot-sum_per_wk3 = 33333 + 333333.
APPEND ls_week_pivot TO gt_weeks_pivot.

************************************ Display regular (source) data in ALV: *******************************
DATA: lo_alv TYPE REF TO cl_salv_table,
      lo_columns TYPE REF TO cl_salv_columns_table,
      lo_column  TYPE REF TO cl_salv_column_list.

 CALL METHOD cl_salv_table=>factory
  IMPORTING
    r_salv_table = lo_alv
  CHANGING
    t_table      = gt_weeks.

  lo_columns = lo_alv->get_columns( ).
  TRY.
      lo_column ?= lo_columns->get_column( 'WK_HEADER' ).
      lo_column->set_short_text( 'WeekName' ).
      lo_column ?= lo_columns->get_column( 'WK_NUMBER' ).
      lo_column->set_short_text( 'WeekNr' ).
      lo_column ?= lo_columns->get_column( 'AMT_PER_WK' ).
      lo_column->set_short_text( 'AmntPerWk' ).
    CATCH cx_salv_not_found.
  ENDTRY.

************************************ Display pivot of source data in ALV: *******************************
lo_alv->get_functions( )->set_all( abap_true ).
CALL METHOD lo_alv->display.

 CALL METHOD cl_salv_table=>factory
  IMPORTING
    r_salv_table = lo_alv
  CHANGING
    t_table      = gt_weeks_pivot.

  lo_columns = lo_alv->get_columns( ).
  TRY.
      lo_column ?= lo_columns->get_column( 'SUM_PER_WK1' ).
      lo_column->set_short_text( 'SumPerWk1' ).
      lo_column ?= lo_columns->get_column( 'SUM_PER_WK2' ).
      lo_column->set_short_text( 'SumPerWk2' ).
      lo_column ?= lo_columns->get_column( 'SUM_PER_WK3' ).
      lo_column->set_short_text( 'SumPerWk3' ).
    CATCH cx_salv_not_found.
  ENDTRY.

lo_alv->get_functions( )->set_all( abap_true ).
CALL METHOD lo_alv->display.
```

What I've tried so far was to create Field-catalog that matches the pivot-structure:

```
    DATA:  fc_tmp_pvt       TYPE lvc_s_fcat,
       fc_acc_pvt       TYPE lvc_t_fcat.
CLEAR: fc_tmp_pvt.
DATA:  counter_i        TYPE i,
       counter_s        TYPE string,
       wk_number        TYPE string.

counter_i = 1.
counter_s = counter_i.
CONCATENATE 'wk_number' counter_s INTO wk_number.

****************** Create pivoted Field-Catalog by looping through SumsPerWeek Table: ******************
FIELD-SYMBOLS: <fs_week> TYPE strct_week.
LOOP AT gt_weeks ASSIGNING <fs_week>.

    fc_tmp_pvt-fieldname = wk_number.
    fc_tmp_pvt-col_pos = counter_i.
    fc_tmp_pvt-coltext = <fs_week>-wk_header.
    fc_tmp_pvt-key = 'X'.
    fc_tmp_pvt-seltext = <fs_week>-wk_header.
    APPEND fc_tmp_pvt TO fc_acc_pvt.

    counter_i = counter_i + 1.
    counter_s = counter_i.
    CONCATENATE 'wk_number' counter_s INTO wk_number.

ENDLOOP.
```

Then I tried to create a dynamic table matching the pivoted Field-Catalog:

```
        ****************** Create Dynamic Table matching pivoted Field-Catalog: ******************
DATA: r_dyn_table TYPE REF TO DATA.
FIELD-SYMBOLS: <t_dyn_table> TYPE STANDARD TABLE.

  CALL METHOD cl_alv_table_create=>create_dynamic_table
    EXPORTING
      it_fieldcatalog           = fc_acc_pvt
    IMPORTING
      ep_table                  = r_dyn_table
    EXCEPTIONS
      generate_subpool_dir_full = 1
      OTHERS                    = 2.

ASSIGN r_dyn_table->* TO <t_dyn_table>.
FIELD-SYMBOLS: <wa_dyn_table> TYPE any,
               <w_field> TYPE any.
APPEND INITIAL LINE TO <t_dyn_table> ASSIGNING <wa_dyn_table>.

FIELD-SYMBOLS: <fs_data> type strct_week.
DATA: lv_index type sy-tabix.

counter_i = 1.
counter_s = counter_i.
CONCATENATE 'wk_number' counter_s INTO wk_number.
DATA: sum_per_wk TYPE i.

LOOP AT gt_weeks ASSIGNING <fs_data>.

    ASSIGN COMPONENT wk_number OF STRUCTURE <wa_dyn_table> TO <w_field>.
    <w_field> = <fs_data>-amt_per_wk.
    sum_per_wk = <w_field>.

    counter_i = counter_i + 1.
    counter_s = counter_i.
    CONCATENATE 'wk_number' counter_s INTO wk_number.
*    read table gt_weeks assigning <fs_check> index lv_index. " Check so the position will never be processed later
*    <fs_check>-check = 'X'.
ENDLOOP.

DATA: gs_layout TYPE slis_layout_alv,
      g_repid TYPE sy-repid.
g_repid = sy-repid.

  CALL FUNCTION 'REUSE_ALV_GRID_DISPLAY'
      EXPORTING
        i_callback_program       = g_repid
        is_layout                = gs_layout
        it_fieldcat              = fc_acc_pvt
          TABLES
        t_outtab = <t_dyn_table>
    EXCEPTIONS program_error = 1
    others = 2 .
  IF sy-subrc <> 0.
    message id sy-msgid type sy-msgty number sy-msgno with sy-msgv1 sy-msgv2 sy-msgv3 sy-msgv4.
  ENDIF.
```

The idea being to display the pivot as shown here: [Pivoted sums per week](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlAVI.jpg) using dynamically created table passed to alv. This is failing right now on line: `CALL FUNCTION 'REUSE_ALV_GRID_DISPLAY'` with exception:

> When calling function module "REUSE_ALV_GRID_DISPLAY", an attempt was made to pass internal table "FC_ACC_PVT" to formal parameter "IT_FIELDCAT". This resulted in a conflict between the formal and actual parameters. The following conditions have not been met: "2, 3"
> (2) The row types of both tables are not compatible.
> (3) The table keys of both tables do not match.

Comment: Please clarify "of course is failing right now". What is the actual symptom, what do you expect instead? Clarify the question too. You must pass the list of columns to display in the parameter `it_fieldcat`.

Comment: `ABAP (NOT sql) dynamic table-pivot` why not sql? [sql pivoting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58582982/911419) is beautiful and more concise comparing to ABAP one

Comment: @SandraRossi: what I mean by "of course is failing" I am getting red screen with error:     
     When calling function module "REUSE_ALV_GRID_DISPLAY", an attempt was ma
     pass internal
    table "FC_ACC_PVT" to formal parameter "IT_FIELDCAT". This resulted in a
     conflict
    (2) The row types of both tables are not compatible.

    (3) The table keys of both tables do not match.

Comment: @Suncatcher - yes. it's beautiful when you know exactly the column names and the number of columns that need to be pivoted. As I mentioned in my question: I do not know what these column names will be. They can be 202201 or 201152 - the code has to accept whatever values in the weeknr column may occur in the source table (as long as they are a string of 6 digits) and transpose those week number rows into columns.

Comment: The syntax error is normal because the type of the parameter `IT_FIELDCAT` of `REUSE_ALV_GRID_DISPLAY` is `SLIS_T_FIELDCAT_ALV`, not `LVC_T_FCAT`.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there is a much simpler solution than converting field catalog object to TYPE `slis_t_fieldcat_alv` by calling `LVC_TRANSFER_TO_SLIS` and then using `REUSE_ALV_GRID_DISPLAY`; Instead all I had to do was this:

```
FIELD-SYMBOLS: <fs_tab> TYPE STANDARD TABLE.
ASSIGN r_dyn_table->* TO <fs_tab>.

CALL METHOD grid->set_table_for_first_display
  CHANGING
    it_fieldcatalog = fc_acc_pvt
    it_outtab       = <fs_tab>.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use REUSE_ALV_GRID_DISPLAY_LVC instead